# How pass variable to 'with' function which has the same name with data frame's column?

Tags: r

I want to get rows from data `mtcar` where `mpg` column equals to some value defined previously. Usually I would like to write this

```r
mpg <- 21
mtcars[mtcars$mpg == mpg, ]
```

But I wonder if can use `with` function.

```r
mpg <- 21
with(mtcars, mtcars[mpg == mpg, ])
```

However this code not work, and I find `R` will use the column `mpg` not the variable `mpg`. I tried `get` function like `data.table` package but still not work.

I know I can change the variable name, but is there any way to use variable which has the same name with data column's name in `with` function?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to extract the `mpg` value from `.GlobalEnv`

```
mpg <- 21
with(mtcars, mtcars[mpg == .GlobalEnv$mpg, ])

#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I want to use this code in a function, `.GlobalEnv` can not be used.

Comment: @Matt Then just capture your function environment `env <- environment()` inside your function. And use `with(mtcars, mtcars[mpg == env$mpg, ])`

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
mpg <- 21
with(mtcars, mtcars[mpg == .GlobalEnv[[mpg]],])
```